# I'm new to coding and am trying to get the sum of these 'y' values, but nothing I've tried seemed to work

Tags: python, key, iterable

So I'm trying to sum up the 'y' values of this code, so I can use it later on. Everything I've tried so far (a lot) didn't seem to work. And I just don't know how to fix it.
This is my code:

```
inventory = {
'x' : {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3},
'y' : {'x': 4, 'y': 5, 'z': 6}}

for key in inventory:
  print(sum(inventory[key]['y']))
```

And this is the error code I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/School-project/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(sum(inventory[key]['y']))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I tried many things, which I don't even remember at this point to be honest. But if somebody could help it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You were super close!

```
inventory = {
'x': {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3},
'y': {'x': 4, 'y': 5, 'z': 6}
}

sum = 0
for key in inventory:
    sum += inventory[key]['y']

print(sum)
```

You were never actually adding any values together, but you had the right idea. The sum() function expects an iterable like a list, and you were trying to use it with a raw integer.

This line:

```
inventory[key]['y']
```

Returns the each value with the 'y' key, and the values you have are integers.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been at this for probably 2 hours now, and got bored because nothing worked, now I can continue!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the *Python* tutorial, on *dictionaries*.
*[Python 3.12.0 documentation — The Python Tutorial — 5. Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)*.

This is similar to *@CDubyuh*'s answer.

```py
a = 0
for k, v in inventory.items():
    if 'y' in v: a += v['y']
```

Output

```
7
```